# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency: Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using a simple spring boot application and I want to connect my database using Hibernate. I am not able to inject my Repository class into my Controller class. Please help. However when I remove the problem causing code, my application is able to scan every component and it works fine. I have created my code through Eclipse.

My starter class

```
package spring.starter;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "spring")
public class Starter {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);

    }

}
```

My Controller class

```
package spring.controller;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class AdminController {

/*@Autowired
private AdminService service;*/

@Autowired
@Qualifier("adminRepository")
private AdminRepository adminRepository;

@GetMapping("/admin")
public List<Admin> getAllAdmin() {
    return adminRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

My repository class: For this class I have tried removing both annotations but that also dint work.

```
package spring.repository;
@Repository
@Qualifier("adminRepository")
   public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<Admin, Integer>{

 }
```

Exception trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [spring.repository.AdminRepository] found for dependency [spring.repository.AdminRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=adminRepository)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data JPA repositories are not detected by the `ComponentScan` annotation. For them you have to either provide the annotation

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "spring")
```

or you change the `SpringBootApplication` annotation as following:

```
@SpringBootAnnotation(scanBasePackages = "spring")
```

This will then cover the custom package configuration for `ComponentScan` as well as `EnableJpaRepositories`.
After one of those changes, you can also remove `@Repository`
 from the repository. That annotation is not meant for Spring Data JPA repository interfaces and has no effect on them.

Comment: did you mean changing to SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "spring") because you mentioned Annotation there. Any ways I tried your both ways but still it gave me same exception.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, my starter class was in the package spring.starter all I had to do is to move this class to one level up in the package structure for example:

```
package spring;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "spring")
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);

    }

}
```

And then it worked. But I have a doubt here. What is the benefit of @ComponentScan then ?

Comment: The SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration and ComponentScan with their default attributes.

All others beans that comes under this boot application class will be  considered for component scan. You can omitcomponent scan. You may get more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)